# Android app builds with Ant on command line but not TeamCity CI server

Tags: android, ant, teamcity

So our Android app builds locally from the command line no problem but check it into SVN and point Team City at it and I get the following errors:

```
[10:47:29][apkbuilder] com.android.sdklib.build.ApkCreationException: 
java.io.FileNotFoundException: 
C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\e7d847312af872ea\bin\classes.dex does not exist
[10:47:29][package-helper] The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:295:
com.android.sdklib.build.ApkCreationException: java.io.FileNotFoundException:
C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\e7d847312af872ea\bin\classes.dex does not exist
[10:47:29][do-only-if-not-library] 
The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:930: The following error 
occurred while executing this line:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:295:    
com.android.sdklib.build.ApkCreationException: java.io.FileNotFoundException:    
C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\e7d847312af872ea\bin\classes.dex does not exist
```

This is new to my but my understanding is that the .dex file contains all the classes. Why wouldn't it be in the bin folder?

Comment: perhaps you are missing the build step where the classes.dex is created?

Answer (score 0):

Kind of foolish, I have to expand the tree in the build log to show the javac step couldn't run because the user running the TC Build Agent process didnt have file permissions on the JDK directory.